# Error al re-renderizar datatable en Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Acabo de empezar mi primer proyecto en next.js con typescript y la idea es hacer una tabla donde se mostrarían los datos provenientes de una base de datos en Mongo. Para probar creé un archivo con un array de objetos y datos simulados con faker (ese sería mi clientData) y todo sale bien, hasta que le doy refresh... ahí me salen 4 errores

Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.

Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.

Probé varias cosas pero la verdad no termino de entender qué está pasando. Agradezco mucho si me dan una mano. Gracias!

```
import {
    Table,
    Thead,
    Tbody,
    Tr,
    Th,
    Td,
    TableContainer,
    Box,
} from '@chakra-ui/react'
import clientData from '../../utils/dataBase'



const data = clientData
const DisplayData = data.map((info: any) => {
    return (
        <tr key={info.id}>
            <td>{info.id}</td>
            <td>{info.date}</td>
            <td>{info.name}</td>
            <td>{info.subject}</td>
            <td>{info.status}</td>
            <td>{info.priority}</td>
            <td>{info.lastChange}</td>
        </tr>
    )
})

export default function TicketsTable() {
    return (
        <Box bg="#ebebeb" w="85%">
            <TableContainer>
                <Table size="sm" variant="striped">
                    <Thead>
                        <Tr>
                            <Th>Id</Th>
                            <Th>Fecha</Th>
                            <Th>Cliente</Th>
                            <Th>Asunto</Th>
                            <Th>Estado</Th>
                            <Th>Prioridad</Th>
                            <Th></Th>
                        </Tr>
                    </Thead>
                    <Tbody>{DisplayData}</Tbody>
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>
        </Box>
    )
}
```

Comment: Me pasa lo mismo que a ti. A la que pongo una tabla en html me da ese error que has puesto. La verdad no lo entiendo.